# Visual Studio Development Server With ISAPI Filter

Tags: isapi

I'm currently trying to develop on my local machine a website that uses an ISAPI filter. Is it possible to configure the Visual Studio Development Server to use an ISAPI filter? I've tried adding the filter to my local IIS7, but that didn't do anything.

Setup:
I'm running Visual Web Developer Express 2010 on windows 7 using the .Net 4 Framework. The ISAPI filter is xqasp in case that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, The local development server is quite limited. Host the site in your local IIS instead and then you can use the ISAPI filter there and it should work as expected.

Just create a new virtual directory in IIS and point it to your project directory.

Comment: Sorry for commenting almost 2 years after you posted, but can you tell me if there is a way to set up the application in Debug mode when running via IIS? I've been trying this for a while, and it seems I need to choose between being able to hit breakpoints and using my custom ISAPI rewriter...